# C# parsing a text file and storing the values in an array

Tags: c#

I am trying to read in a text file which has this format below, into an array:

```
Previous errors were for Test id '1234567' Error id '12345678'
Previous errors were for Test id '1234567' Error id '12345678'
Previous errors were for Test id '1234567' Error id '12345678'
```

What I need to do is to, inspect each line and once it finds the first integer value, store all 7 integers after this i.e. 1234567 and assign it to test id. 
Then move on and do the same for error id i.e. inspect the rest of the line and once it hits the next integer value, store all 8 integers after this and assign it to Error id.

The values stored in the array will then be used in a program to call a database with a stored proc.

My code below at the moment is just reading the whole line into an array, I am just trying to figure out the best way to do above:

```
 List<int> test = new test<int>();
 using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Temp\AccessEmail.txt"))
 {
     string line;
     while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
      {   
         Test.Add(line);      
      }
 }
 Int[] test = test.ToArray(); //converts the list to array
 Console.WriteLine(test.Length); //return the number of elements of array
```

Comment: Is `Previous errors were for Test id ` each per line?

Comment: First problems: there's no such type as `Int`, and there's no such identifier as `Test` in your code. Next, you need to convert each line into an `int` - forget the reading part and the array part; those are easy. Start writing a method which will convert each line into however many integers it needs to read.

Comment: In order to retrieve all the lines from a file, just use File.ReadAllLines which will return you an array of strings - from that you can loop through and do the parsing to ints (using string.split to get at the individual elements of each line)

Comment: Thanks for your help pwas, Jon and auburg.

Comment: Previous errors were for Test id etc are on each line - pwas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very basic solution is read the lines, split them and find valid integers:

```
List<int> test = new List<int>();
List<int> error = new List<int>();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Temp\AccessEmail.txt")){
     string line;
     while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null){   
        //split the line
        string[] parts = line.Split(new[]{"Error"}, StringSplitOptions.None);

        //get valid integers
        test.Add(GetInt(parts[0].Split(' ', '\'')));
        error.Add(GetInt(parts[1].Split(' ', '\'')));
     }
}

//print the number of elements in the lists
Console.WriteLine(test.Count); 
Console.WriteLine(error.Count);
```

---

```
int GetInt(string[] a){
    int i = 0;

    foreach (string s in a)
       int.TryParse(s, out i);

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Hi Fuex, while using: string[] parts = line.Split("Error");I am getting this error "The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments" & "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'". Just wondering if I am coding this correctly?

Comment: Hi Fuex,could I ask you another question about the format of int.TryParse, I've coded it like so:                                   public static int GetInt(string[] a)
{
  try
  {
     int i = 0;
     foreach (string s in a)
        int.TryParse(s, out i);

      return i;
  }     
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {            
    Console.WriteLine("Error - could not return int" + ex.Message);
  }
}    - But it is throwing out this "GetInt(string[])': not all code paths return a value". Just wondering if I am coding this correctly?

Comment: @John Just add a `return 0;` after the try catch blocks.

Comment: Hi Fuex,Using the about code that you specified with int.TryParse return i etc. The value in i is not getting stored anywhere, I presumed that test.Add would store this in the List 'test', when I loop through 'test' to see the integers it contains 0, just wondering if you could assist.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex.Split()
if  you want the text use

> string pattern = @"\d+";

if you want the numbers use:

```
pattern = "[a-z]+";
```

then

> string[] extracted = Regex.Split(sr.Readline(), pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have an array with all the lines of text in, you could just iterate over them, and read out the numbers from each.

One such solution:

```
// Extention method to simplify:
public static string GetNumbersFromPos(this string line, int nrToSkip)
{
    return new string(line.Skip(nrToSkip)
                            .TakeWhile(c => Char.IsNumber(c))
                            .ToArray());
}

// Assume you get this from your array:
var eachLine = "Previous errors were for Test id '1234567' Error id '12345678'";

// Find nr of chars to skip
var beforeFirstId = eachLine.IndexOf("id '") + 4;
var beforeSecondId = eachLine.IndexOf("id '", beforeFirstId) + 4;

// Now use the extention method to get the two number-strings:
var firstId = eachLine.GetNumbersFromPos(beforeFirstId);
var secondId = eachLine.GetNumbersFromPos(beforeSecondId);
```

This will give you the numbers as strings in `firstId` and `secondId`, which you can then store, or parse to int, or whatever you need.